# Process for beginning a Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, web-applications

I'm about to begin a Ruby on Rails project and I'd love to hear how others go through the process of **starting an application design**. I have quite a bit of experience with RoR, but don't have that many *starting from scratch with only a vision* experiences and would appreciate the wisdom of others who've been there.

I'm looking for **an order of events, reasons for the order, and maybe why each part is important**. I can think of a few starting points, but I'm not sure where it's best to begin

- *Model design* and relationships (entities, how they relate, and their attributes)
- Think of user *use-cases* (or story-boards) and implement the minimum to get these done
- Create *Model unit-tests* then create the necessary migrations and AR models to get the tests to pass
- Hack out the *most basic version* of the simplest part of your application and go from there
- Start with a *template* for a rails app (like http://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders)
- Do the *boring gruntwork* first (User auth, session management, ...)
- ...

Comment: I was hoping for more than one answer.

Comment: things to be considered while you implement database-design https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/ruby-on-rails-order-of-migration-generator-matters-in-initial-design/

Answer (score 2):

I found myself looping the following tasks for most projects:

1. Gather User requirements
2. Design database Models
3. Build Views
4. Streamline Layouts
5. Find and learn Plug-ins/Gems
6. Testing
7. User Review/Acceptance
8. Deploy the app
9. Documentation

After these years of working as a freelancer, I think step 1 and 2 are the most important (at least for small projects). Before writing any code, I urge users to *finalize* all UI first. HTML skeleton is better than written document. Users *do not* and *will not* understand software specifications. They can only give feedback *after* they see can click something. So being fluent in building a HTML site is a helpful skill. Sometimes I delegate the task to a partner, as a SA role.

Rails is very good for building an ever-evolving schema. Try to use [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and [data seeding](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding) instead of writing SQL statements directly. I find myself rely on ActiveRecord more and more overtime. The `script/console` is a nice tool to test out those many-to-many relationships and building `:conditions =>`.

I worked on a few legacy database lately, the `establish_connection` and `set_table_name` feature in ActiveRecord glue old and new database elegantly.

I'd also like to use this chance to thank [Ryan Bates](http://github.com/ryanb), I learn a lot of Rails from his [railscasts](http://railscasts.com).